# No 60Hz Refresh Rate option on my 32" 4k external monitor in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, 4k-monitor

In my Ubuntu 20.04 display settings on a Dell Latitude 7490 laptop, I can set my laptop monitor to 1920 x 1080 resolution at 60 Hz, but I cannot set my [AOC CU32V3 32" 4k monitor](https://amzn.to/3gYsnKp) to 60 Hz (see screenshots below), even though the monitor supports it. It feels laggy, so I'd really like to increase the refresh rate to 60 Hz. Any idea how I can do this?

Laptop monitor is 60Hz:
[image]

---

External monitor supports 4k (3840 x 2160 resolution) at 60Hz refresh rate, but I cannot set it to 60Hz:
[image]

---

Notice there's no 60Hz option:
[image]

---

Proof the manufacturer says it supports 60Hz at 4k:

https://us.aoc.com/en/monitors/cu32v3
[image]

---

[Info on my laptop's graphics card (Intel HD Graphics 620):](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/latitude-14-7490-laptop/latitude_7290_7390_7490_tgb/integrated-graphics-controller?guid=guid-0824fafd-d519-4111-ba37-860fc847f75c&lang=en-us)

I'm currently connected with a High Speed HDMI cable in HDMI 1.2 mode. Am I to understand that I must use a USB C to Display Port adapter and the Display Port to get 4k at 60Hz, perhaps, *instead of* HDMI?

[image]

### Related:

1. https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/How-to-have-Latitude-7490-to-use-4k-display-with-60Hz/td-p/6085124

Comment: I wonder if it's a hardware issue, with only Display Port being able to handle 4k at 60Hz, whereas HDMI is limited to 4k at 30Hz on my video card, so I just bought this cable: [USB C to DisplayPort Cable,QGeeM 4K@60HZ Thunderbolt 3 to Displayport Cable](https://amzn.to/356wlOX).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out it was just a hardware limitation of HDMI, so you have to use Display Port instead! So, I bought [this USB C to Display Port adapter](https://amzn.to/356wlOX) for $15 (you can [try this one](https://amzn.to/3bwdvmb) or [this one](https://amzn.to/461vmMp) if that one is out of stock), plugged in my Display Port cable that came with the monitor into it, and voila! It works perfectly! 4k (3840 x 2160 resolution) at 60 Hz is now an option and it works perfectly!

---

Note: if your computer doesn't have any USB-C ports with DP video support built into them, you'll need to use a DisplayLink USB A 3.0 adapter instead, as I explain in great detail in my other answer here: [USB video card adapters for Linux Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1486986/327339). The [$90 Club3D CSV-1477 USB 3.0 Type A to dual 4k 60Hz adapter](https://amzn.to/3Pu2qWo), for instance, is excellent. I've tested it on both Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 with 4k @60Hz video output. It supports 5K @60 Hz single-output or 4k @60 Hz simultaneous dual-output.

Comment: Correct, this was also my solution. HDMI doesn't support 4k@60Hz. USB-C-to-DP1.2 cable is the solution. Thanks for writing it up. Incidentally, you answered my question on whether 4k@60Hz is possible through USB-C-to-DP cable on modern laptops running Ubuntu. Fab!

Comment: But this will only work if your laptop does have DisplayPort on USB-C and not if it just has SuperSpeed USB.

Comment: @w-sky, correct. In that case, see [my other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1486986/327339). I updated this answer accordingly. See above.

Answer (score 2):

You need HDMI 2.0 cable and HDMI 2.0 capable graphic card for 4K @ 60 Hz.
Your laptop only supports HDMI 1.4 hence the limit to 4K @ 30 Hz

https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/Latitude-7490-Connecting-an-external-1080p-and-a-4K-display-lid/td-p/7433161

Comment: 30 Hz as the highest VESA compatible refresh rate, but with tools like xrandr and autorandr you can get it slightly higher. I don't know the maximum refresh rate for full 4K but for UWQHD (3440x1440) it is 56.048 Hz through HDMI 1.4.